# Which update for terraria was Duke Fishron introduced?

Tags: terraria-console

Title says it all. Answer me that. When was Duke Fishron introduced? I want to know because It gets boring fighting the same bosses over and over again.

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out what utility this information has.

Comment: @shanodin, why did you remove the regular tag? Are you speculating that OP is on console?

Comment: @Timelord64 Most likely because the asker has stated in a previous question they're playing the 360 version.

Comment: As @Frank said. Plus, (assuming one doesn't read the tag tip (I assume people don't read things)) it is obvious the console tag is for the console version but it *isn't* obvious the regular tag *isn't* just for everything Terraria related, but is the PC specific version.

Comment: Some one changed my tag.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Duke_Fishron#History) he was introduced in 1.2.4. However he is indeed PC only, so this is potentially of not much use to you given the terraria-console tag.

Comment: There is going to be a 1.2.4 update for Terraria Console and Mobile coming out soon.